# Issue with ModuleWithProviders in Angular 13

Tags: angular

I've created a module and added a service provider to its `forRoot()` static method. Then I've imported the module to `app.module.ts` and also added it to the imports section: `ZooModule.forRoot()`. Now I'm trying to inject the service from the `ZooModule` into `app.component.ts` constructor but it says: Can't find name `ZooService`.
Please, see the screenshots attached. How do I have it working?
Thanks for advance!

> [ZooService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExCan.jpg)
>
> [ZooModule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFemO.jpg)
>
> [AppModule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE3Ny.jpg)
>
> [AppComponent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJJT0.jpg)

I tried to read the Angular documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing: you forgot to import ZooService into your typescript file with AppComponent

```
import {ZooService} from '../path/to/zoo.service.ts
```

second: there will be two instances of ZooService. 1st comes from `{provideIn: 'root'}`. second from `ZooModule.providers`. and the 1st won't have access to animals. and there are cases where 1st instance would be injected with no access to animals which is pretty hard to debug. I would recomment removing `{provideIn: 'root'}` to get rid of such errors

Comment: Yes, I had to import the service first, thanks! )